# Remove rows in MDX query where all (measure) columns are empty

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have the following MDX query

```
SELECT

NON EMPTY
{                  
    [Measures].[Date]   
    ,[Measures].[count]  
    ,[Measures].[Growth]
    ,[Measures].[Growth percentage]
}
ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY
(
    NONEMPTY(
     [Business Unit].[BU Number].[BU Number])
    ,[Department].[Deptnumber].[Deptnumber]
    ,SelectedPeriod
)
ON ROWS

FROM Cube
```

As result I get

```
Bu Number DeptNumber  Period     Date  count  Growth  Growth percentage
1         a           1/1        null  null   null    null
1         a           1/1        null  null   null    null
1         b           1/1        1     null   null    null
```

I only want where at least one field is filled
( count
  Growth 
  Growth percentage 
)
so when I see all nulls that row should be deleted

The non empty does not do that in this example

So how to fix that

thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove the NONEMPTY function (the one without a space between NON and EMPTY)?

Comment: I removed that and the result is the same.

Comment: is null coming through as a string "null" ?  I've amended the table in your question as there seemed to be an extra column....I might have made a mistake : if so please correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
{                  
    [Measures].[Date]   
    ,[Measures].[count]  
    ,[Measures].[Growth]
    ,[Measures].[Growth percentage]
}
ON COLUMNS,
NONEMPTY(
    [Business Unit].[BU Number].[BU Number].Members
     *[Department].[Deptnumber].[Deptnumber].Members
     *SelectedPeriod,
    {
     [Measures].[count]  
    ,[Measures].[Growth]
    ,[Measures].[Growth percentage]
    }
)
ON ROWS

FROM Cube
```

Comment: I'd be very curious to know if this works.   I didn't know you could use more than one measure as the second argument of the Nonempty() function.

Comment: It does.   And it turns out that I did know this, I just forgot that I knew it.   When I've used it in the past I created a calculated set in the WITH clause of the MDX and used it as the second argument.   It worked fine.

Comment: I added a calculated field with IIF and checked with an AND function if all of the measures where empty, in that case I made de Measure.Date Null, so all of the values became null, so the Non Empty function would work

Comment: @John glad you figured it out. Can you either post your own solution as a new answer or click the checkmark on my answer if you used it?

Comment: I used a calculation to check if some values where null, but now it just does not perform anymore. so that is also not an option. The option like the answer I tried, but always gives errors that axis are already used, so I have to give that another try. so sofar no success

Comment: @John please update your question with your latest MDX attempts

Comment: PROBLEM with answer: I get The measures hierarchy already appears in the axis0 axis. so it does not seem valid MDX

Comment: @John what's the definition of SelectedPeriod? Is that a set? Can you post the MDX for it?

Answer (score 0):

I added a member to make the measure.date null if any other where null
that works, but now the performance is not existing. It works for some filters of the data, but 98% it does not gives results after a long time waiting

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Date calc] AS 
(
   IIF( [Measures].[Date] = null  
    AND [Measures].[count] = null 
    AND [Measures].[Growth] = null
    AND [Measures].[Growth percentage] = null, Null, [Measures].[Date]  )  
)
```

And I used
NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin(
        Hierarchize(),
        Hierarchize(), 
        SelectedPeriode
    )
ON ROWS

and that solved the performance problem